# How export output from describe() and describeBy() functions in R into LaTex / CSV?

Tags: r, csv, latex

I would like to use output from `describe()` and/or `describeBy()` functions in my thesis without need to format all tables manually. Is there some way how to export these tables in some more suitable format? Ideally to use it in my LaTex code.

```
> describeBy(data$error_mae, list(data$sim))
: 0.1
  vars  n mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range skew kurtosis  se
1    1 36 0.98 0.62   0.73    0.87 0.23 0.47 2.81  2.34 1.61     1.55 0.1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: 0.2
  vars  n mean   sd median trimmed mad  min  max range skew kurtosis   se
1    1 36 1.08 0.78   0.76    0.92 0.2 0.47 3.51  3.04 1.88     2.44 0.13
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: 0.3
  vars  n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min  max range skew kurtosis   se
1    1 36 1.26 0.81   0.99    1.12 0.48 0.5 3.75  3.25  1.6     1.85 0.14
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: 0.4
  vars  n mean   sd median trimmed mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
1    1 36 1.54 0.95   1.27    1.44 0.8 0.5 3.9  3.41  0.9    -0.42 0.16
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found R package `stargazer` that does everything I need - exports data into TXT format that can be used in LaTex.

This command:

```
library(stargazer) stargazer(tmp[c("error_mae", "error_rmse","error_top_mae","error_top_rmse")], type = "text", 
          digits=1, median = TRUE, iqr = TRUE,
          title="Descriptive statistics",
          covariate.labels=c("MAE","RMSE","MAE (Top-5)","RMSE (Top-5)"),out="table1.txt")
```

produces this output:

```
Descriptive statistics
=================================================================
Statistic     N  Mean St. Dev.  Min  Pctl(25) Median Pctl(75) Max
-----------------------------------------------------------------
MAE          540 2.1    1.2     0.5    1.0     1.8     2.9    4.4
RMSE         540 2.3    1.1     0.6    1.3     2.2     3.3    4.4
MAE (Top-5)  540 0.4    0.9    0.000  0.004    0.01    0.1    4.0
RMSE (Top-5) 540 0.4    0.9    0.001  0.004    0.01    0.2    4.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Some usage tips can be found here: [Using stargazer to report regression output and descriptive statistics in R (for non-LaTeX users)](http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/NiceOutputR.pdf)